# Representing rounding algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integer-programming, rounding-error, step-function

Is there a standard way to deal with rounding in algebra? For example:

```
y = x + round(x/2)
```

Would give 2 when x = [1, 3), 3 when x = [3, 5), etc. This of course ends up creating a step function. EDIT: the function *is* injective, see the comments.

Is there a standard math-y way to represent the above equation, and is it possible to solve for x in terms of y?

For context, I need to know the value of `y` above, as well as `round(x/2)`, both as integers. I'm currently using [algebra.js](http://algebra.js.org/) to simplify my expressions, so extra bonus points for showing me how I might implement rounding using that library.

Comment: You can't solve for integer $x$ in terms of integer $y$ since two values of $x$ give the same value of $y$.

Comment: @EthanBolker While I get where you're coming from, it might be fruitful to graph the function. Unless I graphed incorrectly the $y$ as given appears to be injective, so that wouldn't hold.

Comment: A graph for reference: https://i.imgtc.com/YgRB3G1.png

Comment: The OP says $y=2$  when $x=1$ or $2$.

Comment: ... $y=3$ when $x=2$. Plug it in for yourself. >_>

Comment: Of that also means @jstaab that your implication "[y = 2] when x = [1, 3), 3 when x = [3, 5), etc" is incorrect. You might want to check your work in that respect by plugging in various values of $x$. The graph I believe to be correct is linked in the 3rd comment

Comment: @EeveeTrainer you're right, my bad, I was solving the equation `y = 1 + round(x/2)`, which is probably a clearer example anyway. `y = round(x/2)` would be sufficient too I think.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer You are right. I was wrong to believe the OP. So the question is garbled. The function is injective, so can be inverted, but not with a formula. I will delete my answer. You can write one.

Comment: lol it looks like your post is technically correct anyways @EthanBolker - it applies (well, the first line anyhow) for the question the OP intended to ask about. :P (Plus, this made me think of a question I want to ask myself.)

Comment: Which, to summarize, is that there's no _generalized_ way to solve formulas for any term when there's rounding involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** because the OP keeps changing the question.

The answer below applies to the function
$$
y = 1 + \text{round}(x/2)
$$
which the OP says in a comment is what he meant to ask.

The original question asked about 
$$
y = x + \text{round}(x/2)
$$
which is indeed injective and can be inverted, as @EeveeTrainer has commented.

---

You can't solve for integer $x$ in terms of integer $y$ since two values of $x$ give the same value of $y$.

If $x$ must be an integer then in a computer program you can write the function that computes $y$ from $x$ by looking at whether $x$ is even or odd and acting accordingly. You don't need rounding. For arbitrary $x$ you do need the `round` function.

Comment: I failed to mention that the ranges there are not integers, so for example 2.4 is a valid value of x and would result in y = 3.

Comment: @jstaab That's all the more reason why you can't find $x$ just knowing $y$.

Comment: $x=2.4$ yields 

$$y = 2.4 + \text{round}(2.4/2) = 2.4 + \text{round}(1.2) = 2.4 + 1 = 3.4$$

Comment: @Eeevee you're right, my mistake, though the first x may as well be 1, since @Ethan's point is what I was looking for, because a single y would map to multiple values of x. So is there any way to solve for y in the case of `y = x + round(y/2)`?